# Seven hells (Feed problems, photo posting problems etc)

Tags: facebook, flash, feed, photos

Hare the quick facts

- PLATFORM: Actionscript 3 with Facebook
- SDK COMPILER: FlashDevelop
- PROGRAMMER: Getting an headache :(

I've been writing an application which lets you take a photo from the webcam and posts it to the user photos in a photo album named like my application (which is what FB does when you don't specify an album), then the photo is linked in a new feed post and it's uploaded to my client's web server where my client may approve it to get posted also on his company's Facebook page.

This sounds simple as it should, but I've encountered a huge load of problems of various nature, changed the app hundred times (following the Facebook change of policy mess) but I can't seem to get a satisfying outcome.

These are the ways I tried:

1. Uploading the photo to user's appname autocreated album, getting the URL from Facebook of the uploded photo, then giving the url to the feed to be created, in this way:

   `url = Facebook.getImageUrl(response.id);`

   `var data:Object = { message:'testest', picture:url, description: 'test' };`

   `Facebook.api("/me/feed", feedresponse, data, "POST");`

This worked fine, but I encountered the dreaded "(#341) Feed action request limit reached" after some updates. This is unacceptable for the kind of app I am making.

1. So I read that Facebook changed the policies and they now suggest to use the feed creation dialog available by issuing `Facebook.ui('feed', data);` so I repeated the steps in 1), uploaded the photo to the user album, got the URL from the ID, used that url in the feed creation dialog, but I soon encountered the dreaded "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream", wtf.

3) So I tried to make the image smaller, has some random internet folk suggested, but the error would persist.

4) Then I tried to host those images myself, as on the client's webserver, like some other internet surfer suggested, but this doesn't work too:

```
var data:Object = {
  message: "Hey!",
  picture: "https://<domain>/facebookapp/bin/immagini/27.jpg",
  link: "https://<domain>/facebookapp/bin/immagini/27.jpg",
  name: "moo photos",
  caption: "moo photos",
  description: "You took a picture! yay!"
};

Facebook.ui('feed', data);
```

The feed dialog appears correctly, the feed post is created, but you can't see the picture. The picture which should appear directly in the feed is present only as a link to be clicked by the user.

Examining the feed raw data with the graph api reveals that the "picture" attribute doesn't get set to the feed, like it does in the 1) way:

```
"message": "ppipipi",
         "link": "https://<domain>/facebookapp/bin/immagini/27.jpg",
         "name": "https://<domain>/facebookapp/bin/immagini/27.jpg",
         "caption": "lol my heart out",
         "description": "die in pain!",
         "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/default_app_icon.gif",
         "actions":
```

5) So I tried putting a FBCDN image link i had from the previous steps and it worked! weren't FBCDN not allowed ?? Seems the ones that are already on the server are accepted?

6) I changed the flow of the app and now when I update the photo to the user's album, like this:

```
 var data:Object = { message:'TESTTESTTEST', fileName:'FILE_NAME', image:bitmapdata};
        Facebook.api("/me/photos", uploadDone, data, "POST");
```

`uploadDone` NEVER gets called, either if the upload actually works, or not!

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Ok one slight problem was that uploadDone's signature was different from the one expected, so now it gets called, but still no biggie for other problems.

Comment: Ok, fixed the image in the feed dialog.. Using HTTP instead of HTTPS, not sure if it's because the server's configuration is not 100% correct with the certificates or it just doesn't like https in photos?

Comment: The problem now is that it's using my server to host the images, is there a way to put the image uploaded in facebook album in the feed so facebook will host the image ?

Answer (score 0):

As your post stated that this is an application that needed modification after "policy changes". Maybe you missed that Facebook disabled the `message` parameter.

If you are initiating a dialog with `FB.ui()` it is now up to the user to enter the message he/she wants.

Not sure if this will solve your issue but I have had some experience of Facebook totally ignoring a post I make when it has the `message` parameter.

Comment: It doesn't, but it makes sense and it's useful to know, thanks :)